# Being able to data.map for fetch() responses but on arrays

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I have the following `useEffect` code that I know works for responses that look like this `[{"name":"Agilent Technologies Inc","symbol":"A","industry":"Health Care"},{"name":"American Airlines Group","symbol":"AAL","industry":"Industrials"},{"name":"Advance Auto Parts","symbol":"AAP","industry":"Consumer Discretionary"}]`.

But it doesn't work for the following type of response `{"timestamp":"2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z","symbol":"AAL","name":"American Airlines Group","industry":"Industrials","open":10.9,"high":11.36,"low":10.01,"close":10.25,"volumes":55494100}`. What is the best way I can adjust the code to work? It is throwing an `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.map is not a function`.

```
const [stockData, setStockData] = useState([]); 
const [query, setQuery] = useState("AAL"); 


   useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`PRIVATE_URL_${query}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => 
          data.map(stocks => {
            return {
              name: stocks.name,
              symbol: stocks.symbol,
              industry: stocks.industry,
              open: stocks.open,
              high: stocks.high,
              low: stocks.low,
              close: stocks.close,
              volume: stocks.volume
            };
          })
        )
        .then(stocks => setStockData(stocks)); 

  }, [query]);
```

Comment: Map does work for arrays, map is a function to loop over an array with elements/objects. If data is an array then stocks should be the value of that current iteration.

Comment: how is data in `.then(data =>` looks like? add it to ur question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if you made a mistake with your wording but `.map` is specifically for arrays, looking at your code you try to iterate over an array of objects but you do not have an array of objects you just have an object. Just remove the map and use `data` in your return instead of `stocks`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`PRIVATE_URL_${query}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => 
        return {
          name: data.name,
          symbol: data.symbol,
          industry: data.industry,
          open: data.open,
          high: data.high,
          low: data.low,
          close: data.close,
          volume: data.volume
        };
    )
    .then(stocks => setStockData(stocks));
```

}, [query]);

Comment: That didn't work. Ive just updated the question so it might make more sense

Comment: When you say it did not work, it is probably because `setStockData` is expecting an array.

Comment: How about reverting the original downvote if it was you :-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question, But [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a method of Array, and return a new Array. so if your data is Array and you want to map it. you can try this:

```
     useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`PRIVATE_URL_${query}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => 
          return data.map(stocks => {
            return {
              name: stocks.name,
              symbol: stocks.symbol,
              industry: stocks.industry,
              open: stocks.open,
              high: stocks.high,
              low: stocks.low,
              close: stocks.close,
              volume: stocks.volume
            };
          })
        )
        .then(stocks => setStockData(stocks)); 
  }, [query]);
```

Comment: That didn't work. Ive just updated the question so it might make more sense